# Default username password for Tomcat Application Manager

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans-7

Starting web services in Netbeans just Hello World Program , but this Application Manager makes hectic on this to start ,

Facing this alert message in NetBeans  also `Tomcat Application Manager` Message with user name and password
   I gave the admin and password as credentials it returns invalid username

```
Enter password to unlock your login keyring

The password you use to log in to your computer no longer matches that of your login keyring.
```

What should be default values for user name password in Tomcat Application Manager  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First navigate to below location and open it in a text editor

```
<TOMCAT_HOME>/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

For tomcat 7, Add the following xml code somewhere between `<tomcat-users>` I find the following solution.

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="username" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Now restart the tomcat server.

Answer (score 5):

The admin and manager apps are two separate things. Here's a snapshot of a tomcat-users.xml file that works, try this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  
<tomcat-users>  
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>  
    <role rolename="role1"/>  
    <role rolename="manager"/>  
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>  
    <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>  
    <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>  
    <user username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD" roles="manager,tomcat,role1"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

It works for me very well

Comment: for newer version of tomcat like tomcat 7 it require "manager-gui" to manage app.

Answer (score 0):

To **reset** your keyring.

1. Go into your home folder.
2. Press ctrl & h to show your hidden folders.
3. Now look in your .gnome2/keyrings directory.
4. Find the default.keyring file.
5. Move that file to a different folder.
6. Once done, reboot your computer.